# Overcoming 32-bit limitations, when using a System.Drawing.Graphics surface translated by millions of units

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

### Context:

In .NET WinForms I built a map control so I can plot geometry and render satellite images. As in any 2D projection, the geographic coordinates are mapped to 2D surface. But as you zoom IN, you notice that the resulting 2D coordinates get to the order of Millions of Units as you move to higher latitude and longitude values.

---

### Problem:

The way you can pan/zoom at large pictures such as in a map, is translating the drawing surface using a transformation matrix. The GDI+ uses `float` for internal calculations (as far you can tell by the .NET `System.Drawing` namespace). The issue is that when your `float` grows to millions, you lose your decimal places precision, and things starts to get weird. Even though the screen works in a discrete integral type (multiples of 1 pixel) rendering operations and transformation still need to use `float` math.

---

### Code:

```
public void Render(Graphics gfx, ICamera camera, Polygon polygon) {
    var points = polygon.Points();
    if (!(FillBrush is null)) {
        gfx.FillPolygon(FillBrush, points);
    }
    if (!(OutlinePen is null)) {
        gfx.DrawPolygon(OutlinePen, points);
    }
}
```

As seen below, the map show a filled polygon followed by an outline. Notice that the weird result for the dashed outline, while the fill seems correct. However both operation took the same `Point[]` as input.

[image: Projected Mercator map using GDI+ in Windows]

So the only sensible reasoning is that the GDI+ calculations with floating point will get rounding/truncation errors.

This is evident when I look closer into the values of each coordinate just before they are converted to integers to feed the drawing methods:

[image: Value of 2D Coordinates]

You can already see that the values are either .0 or .5 with the current magnitude of values in the order of few millions. And as you zoom IN even more, the errors will probably get worse.

I had a similar issue when rendering the tiles into place. They also got rounding errors and they would jump 1 or 2 pixels out of alignment sometimes. The way I solved that was to overlap them a little bit.

### Question and ideas:

How can I workaround that GDI+ limitation of losing precision when the graphical surface is translated
by millions of units?

I suppose that the main issue is the `Matrix.Translate()` call which offsets the visible region by millions of pixels. If I could somehow avoid to translate the surface by that much... but doesn't seem possible to avoid that.

Even though I could easily re-write the Matrix class to work with `double` types, the GDI+ still operates in 32-bit `float`.

---

Comment: You identified the problem correctly, graphic engines like GDI+ (and WPF's!) internally use *float* accuracy.  No more than 7 significant digits.  Scale by x1000 or more and inevitably the pixels, converted back to ints for rendering, are going to be off by 1 or more.  Nothing you can do but scale yourself, that's a week of your life you won't get back.  Well, once bitten twice shy.

Comment: Yeah I thought it would be a week too... turned out to be 'only' 5 hours. Thanks to OOP, I wrapped the 'Graphics' class inside a proxy class that intercepts the rendering calls, and apply the X,Y translation. The GDI+ now works in much lower values, and I still use its Transform matrix for Scale and Rotation. So all my rendering now calls the proxy, and problem solved. Pixel perfect image polygons with the least code invasive approach. Easy peasy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing geodedic coordinates requires double-precision math, otherwise you'll loose precision with (projected) high coordinate magnitude values.

I wonder which map projection you use. Normally, projection models requires a projection center, which it is the projection plane origin (0, 0). Setting the projection center to the coordinate of the current map view make projected coordinates values lower in their magnitude (since they are near to the projection center).

Change the projection center each time the map is recentered, and you'll need double precision only at lowest zoom levels.

Comment: It requires double precision for the angles indeed (I am using). And for the 2D I guess you can get away with it for lower zoom, but not in my case. I am using WebMercator. Indeed that is one thing I already thought. I actually used that trick, but it gets annoying and complex to maintain as you build some other code around. But may be the only option...

Comment: I see. Indeed you need to translate yourself the projected coordinates using double precision math, and manage those coordinates in GDI.